# How do I check if a file is under a given directory, in PowerShell?

Tags: file, powershell, directory, contains

I want to check if a file path is in a given directory (or one of its subdirectories), from PowerShell.

Right now I'm doing:

```
$file.StartsWith(  $directory, [StringComparison]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase )
```

but I'm sure there are better ways.

I could do take `$file.Directory` and iterate over all `.Parent`s, but I was hoping for something simpler.

**EDIT**: the file may not exist; I'm just looking at the path.

Answer (score 6):

How about something as simple as:

```
PS> gci . -r foo.txt
```

This implicitly uses the -filter parameter (by position) specifying foo.txt as the filter. You could also specify *.txt or foo?.txt.  The problem with StartsWith is that while you handle the case-insensitive compare there is still the issue that both / and \ are valid path separators in PowerShell.

Assuming the file may not exist and both $file and $directory are absolute paths, you can do this the "PowerShell" way:

```
(Split-Path $file -Parent) -replace '/','\' -eq (Get-Item $directory).FullName
```

But that isn't great since you still have to canonical the path / -> \ but at least the PowerShell string compare is case-insensitive. Another option is to use IO.Path to canonicalize the path e.g.:

```
[io.path]::GetDirectoryName($file) -eq [io.path]::GetFullPath($directory)
```

One issue with this is that GetFullPath will also make a relative path an absolute path based on the process's current dir which more times than not, is *not* the same as PowerShell's current dir.  So just make sure $directory is an absolute path even if you have to specify it like "$pwd\$directory".

Comment: +1.  Being able to specify -path and -fil separately is very convenient.  Learn it, love it.

Answer (score 2):

Since the path might not exist, using `string.StartsWith` is fine for doing this type of test (though [`OrdinalIgnoreCase` is a better representation of how the file system compares paths](http://www.siao2.com/2005/10/17/481600.aspx)).

The only caveat is that the paths need to be in a canonical form. Otherwise, paths like `C:\x\..\a\b.txt` and `C:/a/b.txt` would fail the "is this under the `C:\a\` directory" test. You can use the static [`Path.GetFullPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx) method to get the full names of the paths before you do the test:

```
function Test-SubPath( [string]$directory, [string]$subpath ) {
  $dPath = [IO.Path]::GetFullPath( $directory )
  $sPath = [IO.Path]::GetFullPath( $subpath )
  return $sPath.StartsWith( $dPath, [StringComparison]::OrdinalIgnoreCase )
}
```

Also note that this does not cover logical containment (e.g. if you have `\\some\network\path\` mapped to `Z:\path\`, testing whether `\\some\network\path\b.txt` is under `Z:\` will fail, even though the file can be accessed through `Z:\path\b.txt`). If you need to support this behavior, [these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B.net%5D+unc+drive+full+path) might help.

Answer (score 1):

If you convert your input strings to DirectoryInfo and FileInfo, you won't have any problem with the string comparison.

```
function Test-FileInSubPath([System.IO.DirectoryInfo]$Dir,[System.IO.FileInfo]$File)
{
    $File.FullName.StartsWith($Dir.FullName)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something real quick:

```
14:47:28 PS>pwd

C:\Documents and Settings\me\Desktop

14:47:30 PS>$path = pwd

14:48:03 PS>$path

C:\Documents and Settings\me\Desktop

14:48:16 PS>$files = Get-ChildItem $path -recurse | 
                     Where {$_.Name -match "thisfiledoesnt.exist"}

14:50:55 PS>if ($files) {write-host "the file exists in this path somewhere"
            } else {write-host "no it doesn't"}
no it doesn't
```

(create new file on desktop or in a folder on the desktop and name it "thisfileexists.txt")

```
14:51:03 PS>$files = Get-ChildItem $path -recurse | 
                     Where {$_.Name -match "thisfileexists.txt"}

14:52:07 PS>if($files) {write-host "the file exists in this path somewhere"
            } else {write-host "no it doesn't"}
the file exists in this path somewhere
```

Of course iterating is still happening, but PS is doing it for you.  You also might need -force if looking for system/hidden files.

Comment: I'm not interested in whether the file exists, but whether its path is under a directory.  Also, your formatting is unclear.

Comment: Yeah, the code formatting here doesn't work well for PS.  This is not a full PS1 file, just stuff typed on the PS cmd line.  Your question asked "How do I check if a file is under a given directory..."  It looks like the other answer is also checking for a file, as you asked.  I see your edit, but how can a file have a path if it doesn't even exist?

Comment: I think I get it now, you have this file path stored somewhere, and you want to see if the path part exists beneath some other specified path?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse $directory | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and `
    $_.FullName -match "^$($file.Parent)" } | Select-Object -First 1
```